# Changing the Redux Store caused my App to stop Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm learning React/Redux, and while rewriting my redux store to better store the state and add async thunks, my app stopped rendering. My console shows no errors and the page is blank.

*App.js*

```
import './App.css'
import React from 'react'
import SearchBar from '../features/search/SearchBar'
import Post from '../components/Post'
import Subreddits from '../components/Subreddits'
import { BsReddit } from 'react-icons/bs'

const App = () => {
    let listOfPosts = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        listOfPosts.push(<Post iterator={i} />)
    }
    
  return (
        <main>
            <header>
                <h1>
                    <BsReddit />
                    <span>Reddit</span> Minimal
                </h1>
                <SearchBar />
            </header>
            <div className='post-container'>
                {listOfPosts.map((post, i) => <li key={'post_' + i}>{post}</li>)}
            </div>
            <Subreddits />
        </main>
    );
}

export default App
```

*store.js*

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { postsReducer } from '../features/posts/postsSlice'
import React from 'react'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer
  }
})
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app/App';
import { store } from './app/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
}
store.subscribe(render)
```

I can show more of the code, but i assume the problem is somewhere in these 3 files. I truly don't understand why its not rendering.

Comment: assuming that if you unwrap it from the Provider, it does render?

Comment: @narliecholler still doesnt render. so maybe the problem is the App component itself?

Comment: yes, either create this in a sandbox so we can have a look or manually remove each part until you find where it works. You've removed provider so it is safe its not redux, there must be some errors somewhere? Try adding list of posts to useEffect so it happens on render only too.

Comment: you can see this works - https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-rain-yo65u?file=/src/App.js. Adding your code to the rest of this sandbox and we can delve deeper :)

Comment: @narliecholler After adding the rest of my code to the sandbox I noticed the problem was in the render function. I tried unwrapping the Provider but not unsubscribing render to the store. Once I did this it rendered! So I guess something went wrong in the store but still unsure. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I also have the code on github https://github.com/CoreyRobinsonDev/reddit-client